# Scrollbar logarithmic behavior

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm creating a scrollbar control in Qt from scratch and I managed to calculate the slider center position into a vertical scrollbar. The scrollbar is attached to an edit box and adding lines make the slider go down. The slider is just a small red circle.

The problem now is that while adding lots of lines (by keeping Enter pressed) the slider eventually reaches the end of the bar and goes beyond it where it cannot be seen anymore.

If you try to insert a huge number of newlines on any notepad the slider will eventually become slower and slower (aside from getting smaller and smaller).

How can I accomplish the same with my slider's position?
To make it clear: how can I accomplish a "logarithmic-like behavior" with my custom scrollbar? i.e. how to make the slider slower and slower (in such a way that it will never reach the bottom) when inserting lots of newlines

Comment: The problem here is that you aren't updating the maximum number of lines as your text changes.  The position of the scrollbar should be equal to `available_height * current_line / max_lines`, where `max_lines` should always be kept in sync with what's in your textbox.

Comment: That solved my problem, thanks! Make it an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't updating the maximum number of lines as your text changes.  The position of the scrollbar should be equal to:

```
available_height * current_line / max_lines
```

where `max_lines` should *always be kept in sync* with what's in your textbox.  This ensures that the ratio `current_line / max_lines` never exceeds 1, and hence the position of the scrollbar never exceeds the `available_height`.